# GoogleVR's PermissionsDemo - permissions always denied at Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-permissions, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

Has anyone managed to get a permission granted through Google VR's gvr-permissions-support library?

A demo that is shipped with Google VR plugin that shows how the gvr-permissions-support library can be used to offer the ability to grant runtime permissions. While I was able to run the demo, I was not fortunate enough to be granted a permission.

Specifically, when I click the "Request Permission" button on the demo scene, I get the following exception:

```
 04-22 15:02:53.476 3034-3034/? E/ActivityThread: Activity com.google.gvr.permissionsupport.TransitionVRActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi$1@3ed206d that was originally bound here
                                              android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.google.gvr.permissionsupport.TransitionVRActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi$1@3ed206d that was originally bound here
                                                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1336)
                                                  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1231)
                                                  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1450)
                                                  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1422)
                                                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:636)
                                                  at com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi.init(DaydreamApi.java:838)
                                                  at com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi.create(DaydreamApi.java:141)
                                                  at com.google.gvr.permissionsupport.TransitionVRActivity.onCreate(TransitionVRActivity.java:74)
                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Please note that I'm using Unity 5.6 (2017.1.0b1) and Google VR SDK for Unity version v1.40 (April 2017). My Unity solution's minimum API level is set to Android 7.0 (API level 24).

Comment: What's your Unity and Android version? Plugin version?

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.6 (2017.1.0b1) and Google VR SDK for Unity version v1.40 (April 2017). My Unity solution's minimum API level is set to Android 7.0 (API level 24).

Comment: Were you building the demo scene and running it on your device, or just in the editor?